# How to remove divider between actionBar and it's below layout

Tags: android

How to remove divider between actionBar and it's below layout 
is there anybody to help me out??

```
<style name="AppThemeNoAction" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
       <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/NoActionBarCustom</item>
       <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
   </style>

<style name="NoActionBarCustom" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar" >
       <item name="android:background">@color/color_white</item>
       <item name="android:typeface">normal</item>
       <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
       <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
       <item name="android:height">@dimen/action_bar_product_height</item>
 </style>
```

This is style which I am using...but it's creating a shadow between main actionBar and it's below layout, Thanks.

Comment: add below Line in Activity.

    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add below Line in Activity.

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```